# Unable to load dynamic library 'blackfire'

Tags: installation, blackfire

I create a post today because I have a problem with the blackfire installation.
I read all documentation and install this extension but I have an error message in my command consol.
I did add BlackFire but when I want to config the extension, this message appair :

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'blackfire' (tried: D:/Programmes/WAMP/bin/php/php7.3.12/ext/blackfire (The specified module was not found.), D:/Programmes/WAMP/bin/php/php7.3.12/ext/php_blackfire.dll (The specified module was not found.)) in Unknown on line 0[enter image description here]

I'm sure as a good path and I don't understand why I have this message..
If you can help me,

Thanks in advance and good development !